# How find all addresses with dataSize = 777(example) in all serum network?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, solana

How find all addresses with dataSize = 777(example) in all serum network.
Is there a way?

Comment: Could you give more information on what you're looking for?

Comment: @Jacob Creech 
For analyze the network. Also interesting is the aggregated data for all addresses (type, owner, balance, etc.)

Comment: Right, but we need more information on what accounts you are after, what program these accounts belong to, etc. There's a new guide here to get you started https://solanacookbook.com/guides/get-program-accounts.html but if you want a direct answer, we need the information stated

Comment: @JacobCreech ideally, I would like a similar method like getAccounts where programId is not a required parameter. but I know it's unrealistic.
I downloaded [network snapshots](https://github.com/c29r3/solana-snapshot-finder)
but there is raw block data. maybe there is a way to get the binary data of all addresses in file format?